# Python multiprocessing and SLURM: processes don't run in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, slurm

I need to process a lot of data with one script, so I am trying to run a python script with multiprocessing using SLURM. I am feeling that I am so close to the right answer but every time something goes wrong.

My starter pack includes:

- a text file with arguments; one line of it contains some parameters and arguments that manage the amount of processing data, for example

`2011-02-19 56755 70 2012-01-01 2012-01-04`

The last two arguments mean that 4 days of data should be processed (they are starting day and ending one)

- a processing .py script with a lot of necessary functions
- a main.py script where multiprocessing is used
- a sbatch run.sh file with commands and parameters for SLURM.

So here is my main.py and run.sh script.

## main.py

arguments are tuples of data. If I need to process N days, len(arg_array_filt) = N*M*3 and len(arg_array_map) = N*M.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_array_filt, arg_array_map = myut.get_args(dates) 

    if FILTER:
        pool_filt = Pool()
        pool_filt.map(ft.partial(myut.filt_worker, RESPONSE), arg_array_filt)
        pool_filt.close()
        pool_filt.join()
    if CORRELATE:
        pool = Pool()
        pool.map(ft.partial(myut.map_worker, tmp_date, t0, tt, rock_consts, latitudes, longitudes, deep_coordinates), arg_array_map)
        pool.map(ft.partial(myut.st_reduce_worker, tmp_date, t0, const_r), dates)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

## One of versions for run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n4 # number of tasks

module load python-intel-18.3/3.6
for i in {1..4}
do
    line=`sed "${i}q;d" arrayparams.txt`
    srun -n1 python3 main0.py $line &
done
wait
```

I have run this scheme for only one day of data and know that it takes about 7 minutes. For example the mentioned above run.sh script runs 4 tasks in parallel but the total duration is 23 minutes. And I suppose that more data will requre more time even running in parallel. Can it be overcome? I read that map holds the results until the last process is finished. But their running time is almost the same. I did not find explanations for that.

Also I have issues with map. It does not execute workers for several arguments. I tried to come up with different numbers of CPUs per task in run.sh as well as numbers of processes in pool. Everything looks like map uses only one CPU. Probably I don't understand how to distribute resources...

I have been struggling with this task for weeks, so I will appreciate any help and advices. Thank you in advance!

## UPD

I have found some information about the number of threads, so I have put the next line in run.sh script:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
```

and the next piece of code is in main.py:

```
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = os.environ['SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK']
pool_size = int(os.environ['SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK'])
```

Yesterday I varied the number of threads and pool size and get next results for processing of one day of data:

- 1 cpu/task, `pool_size = 1` --> 1 hour 19 minutes
- 1 cpu/task, `pool_size = 8` --> 14 minutes 49 seconds
- 1 cpu/task, `pool_size = 16` --> 8 minutes 39 seconds
- no any specified parameters as before, but 1 cpu was used --> 7 minutes 39 seconds.

So at the moment I wonder how many threads there are in one CPU? Based on sample timings may I assume that there are 16 threads in one CPU?

Also I have found useful article about submitting hybrid jobs:
https://hpcrcf.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TCP/pages/7289570/How-to+Submit+a+Hybrid+Job

There is an interesting table about the number of CPUs and threads and running time.

Comment: What is `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`?

Comment: @DavisHerring As I understood it returns the number of CPUs which in fact the number of threads in the pool. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: SLURM is commonly used on HPV machines. Do you have MPI available?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, both MPI and OpenMP

Comment: @NataliaGalina: I meant what is its value for your setup (I meant the parentheses as an actual call).  It could be misconfigured and think that only one process can run at a time.

Comment: @DavisHerring oh, sorry! cpu_count() = 16 and I suppose that I have found out this also by timing samples (see UPD in the postt) :)